# DOMException: certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources

Tags: cordova, browser, ionic2

```
this.file.createFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'record.m4a', false).then(() => {}
```

giving the exception

> "DOMException: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources."

in the browser.

Comment: Try different browser than Chrome.